# Visual editor with changelog

Tags: text-editor

I am looking for editor (native or web) for creating WYSIWYG documents with text and images with ability to set "checkpoints" and ability to see difference between documents (yes, like in version control systems) in a good visual way, basically what I need is something like this, but for formated (bold, italic, etc.) text with images:

[image]

Comment: Do you want it to display only the right pane? or 2 panes? You want an unlimited number of "checkpoints" ("snapshots?") right? I think LibreOffice has the concept of "changes" which is a bit similar but no exactly that. You don't care about the output format (RTF, HTML, ODT, etc) right? Free, or what is your budget?

Comment: Do you think [Meld](http://meldmerge.org/) might fit your needs?

Comment: For which operating system?

Comment: In how far is the shown image a WYSIWYG editor?

Answer (score 2):

I think what you're looking for is quite antinomous: WYSIWYG and "see difference between documents". What if one revision of your document has a title with big letters, and another revision has a title with much smaller letters, or page break, or if one image is 1000 px high and another is 150 px? How can you compare all this side by side?

I'm probably biased because I'm using a lightweight markup language and I don't like much wysiwyg, but I've came to this idea especially because wysiwyg tools often produce ambiguous and unclean code, and because you can't easily compare documents when they're not using a lightweight markup language. Besides, when you're used to it, you can easily edit your documents on a server from a ssh connection etc.

Honestly, wysiwyg is not very useful, and it's not very difficult to remember `** **` is for bold, `// //` is for italic etc...

Markdown is well-know and the buzz word at the moment, but there are also other markups, such as restructuredtext, creole, txt2tags (I favor txt2tags).

For checkpoints, use a distributed revision control tool, like Mercurial or Git (you don't need to commit on a server, you can just do it on your computer). It's robust and optimised for text-document.

On windows there is tortoisehg which does this with some easy to use gui and visual tools: http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.org/

Interface when you decide to commit your changes:
[image: mercurial]

If you want to compare different revisions, there is a diff tool included:
[image: mercurial_diff]

Beyond this system, which you can use for individual text files, if you want to have something similar from the web, you can test this online:
http://wiki.txt2tags.org/demos/lionwiki-t2t/index.php?page=main

The same file, edited from the web:
[image: diff web]

And edited with the "meld" tool, for comparing files:
[image: diff meld]

Without a revision control tool like git or mercurial, you can still use it, but you won't have control on the snapshot, it will be automatically done after each save.

Comment: +1 WYSIWYG is more a marketing scheme than a useful tool. See my blog post http://blog.pdark.de/2008/08/31/the-space-between-two-characters/ for more reasons to avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

[Google Drive](http://drive.google.com) document editor should work for you. It isn't perfect as it is *not* a version control system but it does have good versioning despite that.

Things you mentioned/screenshotted that it does **not**have:

- Manual checkpoint setting (they are set automatically as you edit it).
- side-by-side comparison

It supports:

- WYSIWYG with text & images
- Pretty good formatting set
- Free (no ads either)
- Web-app but with offline setup available.
- Revision history; only as a unified diff of each changeset but not bad for documents I've found; see screenshot below:

[image: Revision History]

Comment: Thank you for your response, but the thing is - those two unsupported features are the most important. Whole idea - to see clear what has changed. So I need a) Side to side comparison b) Manually set checkpoints, because in case of automatic checkpoints in gonna be total mess, hard to find what to compare with what...